# Deserialize XML to Class

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML which I am de-serializing,This is my XML

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
<UserInfo xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>  
<UserName>First_User</UserName>  
<Age>25</Age>  
</UserInfo>
```

I have this class

```
namespace MyProject{
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http:/MyProject.ServiceContracts/2006/11", IsNullable = false)]

    [DataContract]
    public class UserInfo
    {
       private string username;

        private string age;

        [DataMember]
        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.username;
            }
            set
            {
                this.username = value;
            }
        }

           [DataMember]
        public string Age
        {
            get
            {
                return this.age;
            }
            set
            {
                this.age = value;
            }
        }

    }
    }
```

and I am doing this

```
     XmlSerializer xmlSerSale = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserInfo));

                        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(myXML);

                        info = (UserInfo)xmlSerSale.Deserialize(stringReader);

                        stringReader.Close();
```

Its giving me exception,

```
{"<UserInformation xmlns=''> was not expected."}
```

how can I fix this?Any alternate way to fix this?
I have to use this in WebService

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declare the namespace in your xml meta descriptors:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http:/MyProject.ServiceContracts/2006/11", IsNullable = false)]
public class UserInfo
{
  [XmlElement]
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  [XmlElement]
  public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

When you do this, you also have to have this namespace in your xml:

```
var foo = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
<UserInfo xmlns='http:/MyProject.ServiceContracts/2006/11' 
xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>  
<UserName>First_User</UserName>  
<Age>25</Age>  
</UserInfo>";

var xmlSerSale = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserInfo));
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(foo))
{
  var info = (UserInfo)xmlSerSale.Deserialize(stringReader);
}
```

Also note the `[DataContract]` `[DataMember]` attributes are ignored by `XmlSerializer`.

UPDATE: if you can't change the xml you have to drop the namespace descriptor from `XmlRoot` attribute. I.E.:

```
[XmlRoot(IsNullable = false)]
public class UserInfo
{
  [XmlElement]
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  [XmlElement]
  public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks, its working can you tell me how can I add xmlns in XML as I am having already generated XML?

Answer (score 0):

The node is named `UserInformation`, while the class is named `UserInfo`. You can either rename the class or use suitable attributes to configure its serialized name. You can look at [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details on controlling serialization with attributes.

Comment: What happens if you use `XmlElementAttribute` instead of `DataMemberAttribute`?

Comment: I am getting this: Attribute 'DataMemberAttribute' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field' declarations:
Well let me check your link too

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document#364401)
For your class it would be:

```
[XmlRoot("Userinfo")]
public class UserInfo
{
    [XmlElement("UserName")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
UserInfo info;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserInfo));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
info = (UserInfo)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```