# Add Namespace attribute in XML Node

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string with XML in it, like this

```
string xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
            <UserInfo xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>  
                <UserName>First_User</UserName>  
                <Age>25</Age>  
            </UserInfo>";
```

I have to add namespace attribute to UserInfo node like this,without removing the existing ones

```
<UserInfo xmlns:'abc'>
```

This is what I am doing

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
```

when I write `xmlDoc.SelectNodes("UserInfo")`,its not selecting any node
How can I add attribute to UserInfo?

Comment: are you re-serializing the XML ?

Comment: Are you able to use LINQ to XML instead of `XmlDocument`? That makes this sort of thing *much* easier.

Comment: Given that the `UserInfo` element isn't *in* a namespace though, I'd expect it to be fine. Can you post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet I can use LINQ too, can you suggest some links for that?

Comment: I have to add namespace attribute as I have to de-serialize it in a class and class contains a namespace

Comment: @JonSkeet check my this question and its accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030943/deserialize-xml-to-class

Comment: Your question is really unclear - you're showing code which calls `SelectNodes`, and that *would* select the appropriate node - what's that got to do with adding attributes? (And again, it should be fine...) Is it only the root node that you need to change?